# jquery show div based on multiple dropdown selectors

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm new to jQuery and my actual attempt of this was very messy and confusing so I tried to make a simpler version with blank jQuery section as to avoid further confusion. I am looking to make a filter system that uses multiple dropdown (select element) menus to only show the results selected in the dropdown.

HTML and CSS:

```css
.person{
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <label>Eye Color:</label>
    <select class="selector eye-color">
        <option value="any">Any</option>
        <option value="greyeyes">Grey</option>
        <option value="blueeyes">Blue</option>
        <option value="orangeeyes">Orange</option>
    </select>

    <label>Hair Color:</label>
    <select class="selector hair-color">
        <option value="any">Any</option>
        <option value="blondehair">Blonde</option>
        <option value="brownhair"> Brown</option>
        <option value="orangehair">Orange</option>
    </select>

    <label>Height:</label>
    <select class="selector height">
        <option value="any">Any</option>
        <option value="short">Short</option>
        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="tall">Tall</option>
    </select>

    <div class="person greyeyes blondehair medium">
        <p>Name: Jeff (Grey Eyes, Blonde Hair, Medium)</p>
    </div>

    <div class="person blueeyes blondehair medium">
        <p>Name: Shannon (Blue Eyes, Blonde Hair, Medium)</p>
    </div>

    <div class="person greyeyes blondehair medium">
        <p>Name: Niomi (Grey Eyes, Blonde Hair, Medium)</p>
    </div>

    <div class="person orangeeyes blondehair medium">
        <p>Name: Charlie (Orange Eyes, Blonde Hair, Tall)</p>
    </div>

    <div class="person greyeyes blondehair medium">
        <p>Name: Elon (Grey Eyes, Brown Hair, Short)</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

jQuery

`

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //If any of the dropdown menus are changed
        $(".eye-color, .hair-color, .height,").change(function() {




    //Turning dropdown menu into string
    var selectedEyeColor = $("select.eye-color").children("option:selected").val();
    var selectedHairColor = $("select.hair-color").children("option:selected").val();
    var selectedHeight = $("select.height").children("option:selected").val();

    var dropdownString = (selectedEyeColor + selectedHairColor + selectedHeight);

    //Turning person into string
    var cardString = $(".person").attr("class");
            console.log(cardString);

    //Comparing if person and dropdown match then show, if not hide

    var dropdownStringv2 = ("person" + " " + selectedEyeColor + " " + selectedHairColor + " " + selectedHeight);

     if (dropdownStringv2 === cardString) {
            $("." + cardString).show(1000);
        } else {
            $("." + cardString).hide(1000);
        }
     });
    });
 </script>`
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66838035/edit) to include your attempted jQuery function so that we may help you with your code.

Comment: Okay will do , it's pretty bad but I have tried my best

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to what help you are looking for , with regards to your code and the desired functionality ?

Comment: I would like the particular grey squares with names to show up when the filter criteria has been met whenever a dropdown box change happens. If the criteria is not met then to hide the grey square. An example of something similar (I'm assuming coded in a different way) can be seen on this link, aside from the fact only one option in each dropdown menu needs to be selected. https://www.asos.com/men/jackets-coats/cat/?cid=3606&currentpricerange=5-470&nlid=mw|clothing|shop%20by%20product|jackets%20&refine=attribute_1047:8278,8406|attribute_10155:6764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your JS code should look something like this :

Here is a working Slackblitz example: https://jquery-zyhypd.stackblitz.io

```
      $(document).ready(function() { 
    //If any of the dropdown menus are changed
        $(".eye-color, .hair-color, .height").change(function() {


    // Hide all options by default whenever a selection was changed.
     $(".person").hide();     

    //Turning dropdown menu into string
    var selectedEyeColor = $("select.eye-color").val();
    var selectedHairColor = $("select.hair-color").val();
    var selectedHeight = $("select.height").val();
    var dropdownString = [];

    if(selectedEyeColor == "any")
    {
      selectedEyeColor = "";
    }
    else
    {
      dropdownString.push(selectedEyeColor)
    }
    if(selectedHairColor == "any")
    {
      selectedHairColor = "";
    }
    else
    {
      dropdownString.push(selectedHairColor)
    }
    if(selectedHeight == "any")
    {
      selectedHeight = "";
    }
    else
    {
      dropdownString.push(selectedHeight)
    }

    if(dropdownString.length)
    { 
      // If filters are applied
      let classesToSearch = dropdownString.join(".")
      $("."+classesToSearch).show();
    }
    else
    {
      // Meaning user has manually reset all dropdowns, so show all values
      $(".person").show(); 
    }
  });
});

And some of the classes in your HTML example were incorrect, so I've corrected them below too : 

<body>

  <label>Eye Color:</label>
  <select class="selector eye-color">
        <option id ="-1" value="any">Any</option>
        <option id ="grey" value="greyeyes">Grey</option>
        <option id="blue" value="blueeyes">Blue</option>
        <option id="orange" value="orangeeyes">Orange</option>
    </select>

  <label>Hair Color:</label>
  <select class="selector hair-color">
        <option value="any">Any</option>
        <option value="blondehair">Blonde</option>
        <option value="brownhair"> Brown</option>
        <option value="orangehair">Orange</option>
    </select>

  <label>Height:</label>
  <select class="selector height">
        <option value="any">Any</option>
        <option value="short">Short</option>
        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="tall">Tall</option>
    </select>

  <div class="person greyeyes blondehair medium">
    <p>Name: Jeff (Grey Eyes, Blonde Hair, Medium)</p>
  </div>

  <div class="person blueeyes blondehair medium">
    <p>Name: Shannon (Blue Eyes, Blonde Hair, Medium)</p>
  </div>

  <div class="person greyeyes blondehair medium">
    <p>Name: Niomi (Grey Eyes, Blonde Hair, Medium)</p>
  </div>

  <div class="person orangeeyes blondehair tall">
    <p>Name: Charlie (Orange Eyes, Blonde Hair, Tall)</p>
  </div>

  <div class="person greyeyes blondehair short">
    <p>Name: Elon (Grey Eyes, Brown Hair, Short)</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was great, that Slackblitz didn't load for me it just continuously buffered the entire time.

Comment: Your welcome :)  Could you please mark my answer as the chosen answer for your query? It'll help me earn some rep on StackOverflow  :) Also, about Slackblitz, please try loading this one https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-zyhypd

Comment: Sure, that linked worked too, thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure ! Happy to help

Comment: Sorry for the trouble again, @mughilsinghMTS. Could you also please upvote my answer, it it is  not too much to ask ?   :)

Comment: Hi, I did try but I don't have enough Karma for it to be public. I had another question if you were available. I have come into an issue in which I have too many results on one page, how would you go about separating the filter results into pages with a pagination?